# Vertx 4.2.1 Redis ConfigReader issue

Tags: vert.x, vertx-redis-client

Running into some strange issues while using redis 6.2.6 as the config server. The config is stored using the HSET commands

HSET appt-src-svc-local vertx '{"listen.port": 8080}'
HSET appt-src-svc-local mongo '{"host":"127.0.0.1", "port":27017}'
...

When using Redis 4, the config can be retrieved correctly. If we switch to V 6.2.6, the RedisConfigStore is unable to parse the Response correctly.

Any help will be much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I believe the vertx-config hasn't been verified to work correctly with the new protocol negotiation feature to support both old and new servers. For now, you could try to force the protocol to fall back to RESP2 (old one) and open an issue on GitHub to test and support any protocol.

To disable the protocol negotiation, you need to configure redis client with:

```
protocolNegotiation: false
```